# not retrieving id from browser url when clicking on back button

Tags: php, mysql

I found a problem in my code, when I want to remove a user from database, it has to remove him, the code for removing works perfect, but afterwards, the if condition shows that the user has been removed and I have a Back button there, I click on it and it should redirect me back to the classroom with the rest of the users in it. Classroom is identified by ID of course, but when I click on Back, it shows me classroom without an ID of a class...so its not getting ID...

```
// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id_student=$_GET['id_student'];
$id_trieda = $_GET['id_triedy'];
// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id 
$zmaz='DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id_student="'.$id_student.'" AND id_triedy="'.$id_trieda.'"'; 
mysqli_real_escape_string($prip, $zmaz);
$row = mysqli_query($prip,$zmaz);


// if successfully deleted

if($row){

echo "Študent bol úspešne vymazaný.";
echo "</br>";
echo "<a href='./trieda.php?id_triedy=".$_GET['id_triedy']."'>Späť do triedy<a/>";

}

else {
echo "Chyba";
}
?>
```

EDIT:

```
// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id_student=$_GET['id_student'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id 
$zmaz="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id_student='$id_student'";
$result=mysql_query($zmaz);

// if successfully deleted

if($result){
    $id_trieda = $_GET['id_triedy'];
echo "Študent bol úspešne vymazaný.";
echo "</br>";
echo "<a href='./trieda.php?id_triedy=".$id_trieda."'>Späť do triedy<a/>";

}

else {
echo "Chyba";
}
```

here is edited code which is similar to one that is working when I add a student into the class and then there is a Back button again, but it works....so problem will be in deleting the student, it cant find the ID of class he was in..i think..but I have no idea how to get the ID of the class before he is removed..

Comment: In your Back link, try using `$id_trieda` instead of `$_GET['id_triedy']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the page you linked to in your comment, I see the problem - you aren't passing `id_triedy` in your zmazat link. It reads:

`http://www.xxx.xx/project/zmazat_studenta.php?id_student=15`

Where it should read:

`http://www.xxxx.xx/project/zmazat_studenta.php?id_student=15&id_triedy=18`
(or whatever the relevant id_triedy is).

Then the `$_GET['id_triedy']` in your question code actually has something to get.

You should really build in a check for this kind of thing:

```
if(isset($_GET['id_triedy'])){
  $id_trieda = $_GET['id_triedy'];
} else {
 echo 'No trieda ID';
}
```

This will check the URL for `id_triedy` and tell you if it's not there.

Comment: well but it will tell me that there is no trieda ID, will it solve the problem if i put it in? cause I dont see a solution in your code

Comment: Read my answer again. The problem is not in the code in your question, it is in the fact that **you are not including id_triedy in the link to `zmazat_studenta.php`**, so you are trying to `$_GET` a parameter that does not exist. You need to edit `trieda.php`, not `zmazat_studenta.php`. The `isset` check is not necessary, it's just good practice.

Comment: I see. Thanks buddy, I was tired last night so I didnt get it :D It works perfect now, thanks :)

Comment: u got it :) and please mark this question as useful, for me :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the trieda.php the file that contains the Classroom?  If so, this line should be amended:

```
echo "<a href=\"./trieda.php?id_triedy=".$_GET['id_triedy']."&id_student=".$_GET['id_student']."\">Späť do triedy<a/>";
```

It looks like you left out the id_student in the URL

Comment: I may be wrong, but the only reason the student_id is being included as a URL parameter in the code above is because he is deleting that student. The link then points back to the Classroom page -  which suggests multiple students. A) why would you need the student ID to display the whole classroom and B) the student has just been deleted anyway, so his ID won't exist.